# How to stop a Callable submitted to ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to implement a sample application to test `Callable` and `ExecutorService` interfaces.

In my app I have declared:

```
ExecutorService exSvc = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

Then:

```
Future<Integer> test = exSvc.submit(
    new Callable<Integer>() {
        public Integer call() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            return 1;
        }
    });
```

Now I'm trying to stop the process before it terminate, I'm using `exSvc.shutdownNow()` but it doesn't work.

To stop gracefully a classical `Thread` I usually use some kind of *condition variable*. Which is a common approach to follow with `ExecutorService`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Future.cancel(true)` and `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` use thread interruption. As long as you don't make uninterruptable blocking calls in your task, all you need is to handle interrupted condition correctly, something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    // Uses isInterrupted() to keep interrupted status set
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        // Cannot use InterruptedException since it's checked
        throw new RuntimeException(); 
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

If you make uninterruptable blocking calls (such as network IO), things become more complex, you need to interrupt them manually somehow, for example, by closing the underlying sockets.

Comment: Is there a way to stop the process without using thread interruption?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly do you want. `shutdownNow()` already uses interruption.

Comment: Yes, infact I'm asking how to stop it **without** thread interruption. Using `shutdownNow()` is the only way to stop a thread submitted to an `ExecutorService`?

Comment: @davioooh: You can do it using a condition variable, but it's not much different - thread interruption status is just a built-in condition variable for this case.

Comment: @axtavt using the shutdown will bring down the entire executorService.. THis executor service might also be processsing few more threads...

Comment: Would a file read from the disk be considered uninterruptable call? I starting a thread for each file that I want to search and when the result is found, I want to kill all the still running threads, but 'ExecutorService.shutdownNow()' is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it with a `FixedThreadPool`, hope it's of some help.

```
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

    List<Future<Void>> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfJobs; i++) {
        MyCallableJob job = new MyCallableJob (...);
        results.add(pool.submit(job));
    }

    for (Future<Void> result : results) {
        try { result.get(); }
        catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ignorable) { }
    }

    pool.shutdown();
```

Comment: How this is related to question? How do Fixed Thread Pool can stop a callable?